# Incorrect syntax near 'datetime'. : 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'datetime'.

when running this code of mine:

```
private static string connectionString = "Data Source=1.1.1.1;Initial Catalog=rs;User Id=rs;Password=rs";

public static List<Cal> getEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    List<CalendarEvent> events = new List<CalendarEvent>();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [ID], [Name], [Room], [Time-in], [Time-out] FROM [rs].[dbo].[res_time] WHERE [Time-in]>=[@Time-in] AND [Time-out]<=[@Time-out]", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@Time-in]", start);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@Time-out]", end);

    using (con)
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            CalendarEvent ce = new CalendarEvent();
            ce.id = (int)reader["id"];
            ce.title = (string)reader["Name"];
            ce.description = (string)reader["Room"];
            ce.start = (DateTime)reader["Time-in"];
            ce.end = (DateTime)reader["Time-out"];

            events.Add(cevent);
        }
    }

    return events;
}
```

Comment: What is the declared data type of the `Time-in` and `Time-out` columns?

Comment: it was datetime

Comment: Which line is the error on, and is it a `SQLException`, or is it a compiler error for implicit conversion??

Comment: I got a compiler error like An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'datetime'.

Comment: Okay, that's not a compiler error, that's a runtime exception. Now, which line does the message say that the exception occurred on?

Comment: in this line, 
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
but I got an error of Incorrect syntax near 'datetime'.

Comment: Alright, now we're making progress. In the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table in the database, the declared type for the 2 columns is SqlDbType.DateTime, right? Not Date, or DateTime2, or something else?

Comment: You shouldn't use (nor need, really) `[]` brackets around *parameter* names. Just use simple names for them that don't require quoting.

Comment: yes datetime is the declared data type

Answer (score 0):

The `AddWithValue()` method can be problematic for dates and times. Use

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("[@Time-in]", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = start;
cmd.Parameters.Add("[@Time-out]", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = end;
```

You can read this [article](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) for more information on the limitations of the `AddWithValue()` method. The gist of it is that since it has to infer the correct data type, sometimes it gets is wrong. This is especially true for dates and times.

Using this overload of the `Add()` method specifies the exact data type that was declared when the column was created on the table, helping to ensure that the correct type is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, are you trying to return a `List<Cal>` or a `List<CalenderEvent>`?

To answer your question, you need to parse it manually in Visual Studio

```
ce.start = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Time-in"]).ToString();
```

This is assuming that your column data is in the proper format for the conversion to work.

---

**UPDATE:**

Ok I screwed up my .ToString()

Try this one:

```
// I moved the .ToString() inside the Convert function
ce.start = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Time-in"].ToString());
```

You're getting the implicit conversion error because its applying the .ToString() AFTER the parse which means you're trying to put a string value into a DateTime variable. My bad!

Comment: I get an error Cannot implicitly convert type "string" to System.dateTime

Comment: what's the format that you're storing your data in SQL?

Comment: Can you show a sample of the Time-In? it might be a conversion format problem

Comment: datatype is datetime

Comment: what do you mean sample?

Comment: what is the value that is stored in your database under [Time-in]

Comment: is it like 2018-02-05 17:03:28.270 for example?

Comment: this is the sample value  1900-01-01 07:00:00.000

Comment: Please try my editted answer, I had made a mistake. Your conversion should be working now